# JOIN the same table on two columns

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I use JOINs to replace country and product IDs in import and export data with actual country and products names stored in separate tables. In the data source table (*data*), there are two columns with country IDs, for origin and destination, both of which I am replacing with country names.

The code I have come up with refers to the *country_names* table twice – as *country_names*, and *country_names2*, – which doesn’t seem to be very elegant. I expected to be able to refer to the table just once, by a single name. I would be grateful if someone pointed me to a more elegant and maybe more efficient way to achieve the same result.

```
SELECT
  country_names.name AS origin,
  country_names2.name AS dest,
  product_names.name AS product,
  SUM(data.export_val) AS export_val,
  SUM(data.import_val) AS import_val
FROM
  OEC.year_origin_destination_hs92_6 AS data
JOIN
  OEC.products_hs_92 AS product_names
ON
  data.hs92 = product_names.hs92
JOIN
  OEC.country_names AS country_names
ON
  data.origin = country_names.id_3char
JOIN
  OEC.country_names AS country_names2
ON
  data.dest = country_names2.id_3char
WHERE
  data.year > 2012
  AND data.export_val > 1E8
GROUP BY
  origin,
  dest,
  product
```

The table to convert product IDs to product names has 6K+ rows. Here is a small sample:

```
id      hs92    name     
63215   3215    Ink  
2130110 130110  Lac  
21002   1002    Rye  
2100200 100200  Rye  
52706   2706    Tar  
20902   902     Tea  
42203   2203    Beer     
42302   2302    Bran     
178703  8703    Cars
```

The table to convert country IDs to country names (which is the table I have to JOIN on twice) has 264 rows for all countries in the world. (**id_3char** is the column used.) Here is a sample:

```
id      id_3char    name     
euchi   chi         Channel Islands  
askhm   khm         Cambodia     
eublx   blx         Belgium-Luxembourg   
eublr   blr         Belarus  
eumne   mne         Montenegro   
euhun   hun         Hungary  
asmng   mng         Mongolia     
nabhs   bhs         Bahamas  
afsen   sen         Senegal
```

And here is a sample of data from the import and export data table with a total of 205M rows that has the two columns *origin* and *dest* that I am making a join on:

```
year    origin  dest    hs92    export_val  import_val   
2009    can     isr     300410  2152838.47  3199.24  
1995    chn     jpn     590190  275748.65   554154.24    
2000    deu     gmb     100610  1573508.44  1327.0   
2008    deu     jpn     540822  10000.0     202062.43    
2010    deu     ukr     950390  1626012.04  159423.38    
2006    esp     prt     080530  2470699.19  125291.33    
2006    grc     ind     844859  8667.0      3182.0   
2000    ltu     deu     630399  6018.12     5061.96  
2005    usa     zaf     290219  2126216.52  34561.61     
1997    ven     ecu     281122  155347.73   1010.0
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: This is the best way to do it. You could give more descriptive aliases though, e.g. `originName` and `destinationName`

Comment: I have added samples per Gorgon’s request.

Comment: But if this is the best way to do it, then that’s it. I will give more descriptive aliases, thanks for the suggestion, HoneyBadger.

Comment: For next time, when you give sample data, it would be nice if the data from different tables matches...

Comment: This is yet another faq duplicate that is a google away. Please read [ask] & its links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you already have it done such that it can be considered good enough to just use as is :o)

Meantime, If for some reason you `really-really` want to avoid two joins on that country table - what you can do is to materialize below select statement into let's say `OEC.origin_destination_pairs` table

```
SELECT 
  o.id_3char o_id_3char,
  o.name o_name,
  d.id_3char d_id_3char,
  d.name d_name
FROM `OEC.country_names` o
CROSS JOIN `OEC.country_names` d
```

Then you can just join on that new table as below

```
SELECT
  country_names.o_name AS origin,
  country_names.d_name AS dest,
  product_names.name AS product,
  SUM(data.export_val) AS export_val,
  SUM(data.import_val) AS import_val
FROM OEC.year_origin_destination_hs92_6 AS data
JOIN OEC.products_hs_92 AS product_names
   ON data.hs92 = product_names.hs92
JOIN OEC.origin_destination_pairs AS country_names
   ON data.origin = country_names.o_id_3char
  AND data.dest = country_names2.d_id_3char
WHERE data.year > 2012
  AND data.export_val > 1E8
GROUP BY
    origin,
    dest,
    product
```

The motivation behind above is cost of storing and querying in your particular case
Your `OEC.country_names` table is just about 10KB in size
Each time you query it you pay as if it is 10MB (Charges are rounded to the nearest MB, with a minimum 10 MB data processed per table referenced by the query, and with a minimum 10 MB data processed per query.)

So, if you will materialize above mentioned table - it will still be less than 10MB so no difference in querying charges
Similar situation with storing that table - no visible changes in charges

You can check more about pricing [`here`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing)

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. In this instance, the cost of querying this table twice is not a concern, but yours is a useful approach to keep in mind. Thank you. :+)

Comment: btw - even if you have 10 joins of the same table in a query  - you pay only once for the size of table - not 10 times :o)

Comment: Didn’t know that. Thanks!