# SQL: How to join the same table multiple times?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I have two tables, and I need to join the second table two times for two different columns.  The tables are in the following format:

Table 1: trip_details

```
column            type
name              string
start_country_id  int
end_country_id    int
```

Table 2: country_info

```
column   type
id       int
country  string
```

I would like to get the Name, Start Country, and End Country.

This would be my attempt at it:

```
SELECT
trip_details.name AS "Name",
country_info.country AS "Start Country",
country_info.country AS "End Country"

FROM
trip_details

LEFT JOIN country_info ON country_info.id = trip_details.start_country_id
LEFT JOIN country_info ON country_info.id = trip_details.end_country_id
```

From what I see, the problem is with the join since I'm using "country_info.country" twice in my Select clause.  What is the best way/practices for these situations?

**EDIT:**
Not sure if there are other ways of doing this, but this is only part of my SQL query so I do need to use a LEFT JOIN

Comment: Incredibly similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48721435/1587819) question. Only half an hour apart!

Comment: @HoneyBadger And why not? Just more in an endless stream of unresearched duplicates.

Comment: Hi. Next time please make some effort google your question, eg your current title, so you don't ask yet another duplicate question. Also see [mcve].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having two `join` clauses is the right way to go. You're just missing giving them different aliases in order to distinguish between the two:

```
SELECT    td.name AS "Name",
          sci.country AS "Start Country",
          eci.country AS "End Country"
FROM      trip_details td
LEFT JOIN country_info sci ON sci.id = td.start_country_id
LEFT JOIN country_info eci ON eci.id = td.end_country_id
```